# Facebook Page notifications in OSX 10.8.2 Notification Center

Tags: macos, facebook, notifications

I currently have my Facebook account linked up to my Notification Center on my Macbook Pro - great!

However, I do have a Facebook page (relatively low traffic) and I'd like to receive notifications from it as well as my personal facebook page in Notification Center. I am the owner and sole admin for this Facebook page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I would not use OS X Notifications, but would instead use [Growl](http://growl.info), and a management tool such as [Babble](http://www.rajbains.com/babble/), which supports both multiple Facebook accounts, and Growl notifications.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [Glow for FB](http://www.glowforfb.com/) ($0.99 in the Mac App Store). I find that its notifications are much more consistent and reliable as opposed to the built-in Facebook notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Only one Facebook account can be used at a time. There is just no way to add a second account.

You could try to forward the Page notifications to your account, if there is anything that allows you to do that.

Comment: A page isn't a separate account. Facebook segments the notifications, though—for example, on iOS you don't get notifications about your page unless you have the Pages app installed, even when the personal account managing the page is setup in iOS or in the primary Facebook app.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a kludge, but you could enable email notifications for your page on Facebook, and enable Mail notification on OSX.